# Enumerating the shell with Next > 1

Tags: c#, shell, com

All sample codes anywhere on the net just don't question the habit of passing 1 as the first argument to an enumeration interface `Next()` call. Yet the documentation clearly promises that more than one items can be obtained in one call. As it can be seen in this code fragment, doing so would tremendously speed up the process of counting the files in a folder (actually, the fundamentally similar WPD interface works that way).

```
string FolderPath = @"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\<Phone-USB-ID>\Internal storage\Pictures\Test";
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(FolderPath, IntPtr.Zero, typeof(IShellItem).GUID, out IShellItem item);
item.BindToHandler(IntPtr.Zero, BHID_SFObject, typeof(IShellFolder).GUID, out IShellFolder folder);
folder.EnumObjects(IntPtr.Zero, SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, out IEnumIDList list);
uint count = 0;
try {
  do {
    //var ObjectIDs = new ObjectIDLargeArray();
    //var pidl = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ObjectIDs));
    //Marshal.StructureToPtr(ObjectIDs, pidl, true);
    //var pidl = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(100 * IntPtr.Size);
    int hr = list.Next(100, out var pidl, out uint fetched); // <<<<<
    if (hr == 0)
      count += fetched;
    if (fetched == 0)
      break;

    //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pidl);
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pidl);
  }
  while (true);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine(e);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal class ObjectIDLargeArray {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
  public IntPtr[] IDs;
}
```

The documentation and the usage on the web is not entirely clear about whether the caller has to allocate the buffer for the IDs returned but as can be seen from the code, I tried all approaches, both a specific array and an allocated block of memory. For very small values like 2 and 3, the shell might simply return garbage in `fetched`. For anything larger, an access violation exception.

Just to put it into a perspective of why it's important: with a newly connected phone, no previous caching, counting the files in a folder of 500 pictures takes about 15 (!) seconds. The second time with data already cached, 3 to 4. Needless to say, even the second is unacceptable for a mere file count but 15 seconds are absolutely stupid. With the otherwise mediocre speeds of WPD but with a 100-step count, a few hundred ms at most.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but there's no point assigning anything to a local variable that's passed as an `out` parameter to a function.

Comment: Well, khhm, where do you see anything like that? -- Oh yes. Of yourse, if the pidl is predefined, there is no type there. That's why I said I can't be absolutely and positively sure the MSDN documenation is perfect.

Comment: The doc clearly states that you must allocate the array of celt elements, but only the array. Items in the array can be null or not, but they will be allocated (or not) on return (so you need to loop through the fetched ones and free them one by one). Also, even if the interface implementer may support celt > 1, it doesn't mean it has to. If it doesn't, you will ask for 10 and it will put 1 in fetched (or 0)

Comment: Yes, I know the supposed operation but my problem is that is doesn't do that. :-) With the array duly passed, all I get is a nice access error. Only celt = 1 works.

Comment: you code is broken, shouln't be out, you *must* allocate and pass an array, and only free the fetched items

Comment: You're right, the only thing I took for granted was the interface definition and that turns out to be fawlty...

Comment: Faulty, bother, no edit after some time. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Solved courtesy of the new C# 7.2 feature, `in` parameters:

```
internal interface IEnumIDList {
  [PreserveSig]
  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
  HResult Next(uint celt, in IntPtr rgelt, out uint pceltFetched);
}
```

That makes it play all right with both the preallocated array and the single value case. It's not really that much faster, unfortunately...